# How to view history of a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When we replace view in ORACLE, how to view the version, time, and SQL script of the view that being changed?

Comment: Oracle does not maintain edit history. You should use a version control system.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to your requirement is using [flashback query](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-query-10g).

Also note from Oracle11g that there is a retention period for your Flashback data archive(FDA) prior to which it was dependent on UNDO
(UNDO_RETENTION) parameter

You can retrieve the SQL of the view at a particular point in time using the below query

```
 SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      USER_views AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP(
        '10-JUL-2022 12:50:13', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
      ) 
    WHERE 
      view_NAME = 'TEST_VIEW';
```

To know the timestamp at a particular time use the below

```
 SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      USER_objects AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP(
        '10-JUL-2022 12:50:13', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
      ) 
    WHERE 
      object_NAME = 'TEST_VIEW';
```

Comment: I have 'grant flashback on myschema.view_name to myschema' and it grant successfully but i still cannot use the 'as of timestamp'. Refer to https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2493673/privilege-required-for-as-of-timestamp-clause

Comment: you have to grant it to user_views and user_objects

Comment: could you give by example? @psaraj12. I grant flashback on user_views to myschema; but it said `ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself`

Comment: use the below grant execute on dbms_flashback to myschema;
grant flashback any table to myschema;

Comment: what database version are you using

Comment: 12.2.0.1.0. it seem I don't have that privileges (Need other DB admin to grant), but I think this privilege should be granted by default because if user can change the view, they can see it history too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246339/discussion-between-hao-hao-and-psaraj12).

Comment: @HaoHao What you're describing is the purpose of a code management repository like Git, not the database itself. Oracle is not a content management system: Flashback will only show recent changes, and likely not a complete history, as it is dependent on the content of the UNDO tablespace. It also requires ARCHIVELOG mode, supplemental logging, and automatic undo management. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-9FEB8DBB-7763-49C2-A1D2-97B4DFF85AC1.